# Каким плагином можно реализовать такую функциональность?

Tags: wordpress

Интересует, плагин для выбора услуги( например заказать фотографа) на сайте?
Подскажите какой плагин может мне помочь, установить на сайте сделанном на wordpress такой функционал, чтобы пользователь мог заказывать себе услугу (типа фотографа, аниматора, тамаду на свадьбу) . Чтобы содержалось краткое портфолио например фотографа с его работами , телефон и контакты.

И еще такое требование чтобы были фильтры.

Но чтоб это был не магазин , там цен не должно быть.

Вот пример страницы с уже реализованным функционалом: https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-reception-venues-houston-tx?sort=featured

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы сделать услуги достаточно зарегистировать пост тип "Услуги" через https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type. Затем добавить нужные дополнительные поля через плагин Advanced Custom Field.

Для реализации фильтров можете сделать нужные https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy и через GET параметры передавать нужные набор терминов и делать выборку по этим терминам.